# Spatial wavelength

Tags: image-processing, spatial

I was reading a [paper on motion magnification](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/papers/vidmag.pdf), *Eulerian Video Magnification for Revealing Subtle Changes in the World*  by MIT CSAIL researchers,

where the equation (14) of the paper uses spatial wavelength. I was going through the source code and the wavelength is calculated by:

$$\lambda = \frac{\sqrt{\text{vidHeight}^2+\text{vidWidth}^2}}{N}$$
where $N$ is an experimental constant.

Can anyone explain where the formula for spatial wavelength came from?

Comment: I can't tell you, but you do realize that the $\sqrt{\cdots}$ term is the length of the diagonal of a square of dimension $\text{vidHeight}\times\text{vidWidth}$, and that this is probably just the length of something whose width and height can be measured?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes I realize that... I just want to know why it's called the spatial wavelength

Comment: because it's the inverse of a spatial frequency.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Doesnt Fourier analysis give spatial frequency? Is it just the inverse of the above equation? Sorry, I am new to image processing